# awk: Preserve multiple field separators

Tags: bash, awk, separator

I'm using awk to swap fields in a filename using two different field separators. 
I want to know if it's possible to preserve both separators, '/' and '_', in the correct positions in the output.

Example:

I want to change this:

/path/to/**example_file**_123.txt

into this:

/path/to/**file_example**_123.txt

I've tried:

```
awk -F "[/_]" '{ t=$3; $3=$4; $4=t;print}' file.txt
```

but the field separators are missing from the output:

```
path to file example 123.txt
```

I've tried preserving the field separators:

```
awk -F "[/_]" '{t=$3; $3=$4; $4=t; OFS=FS; print}' file.txt
```

but I get this:

```
[/_]path[/_]to[/_]file[/_]example[/_]123.txt
```

Is there a way of preserving the correct original field separator in awk when you're dealing multiple separators?

Comment: Don't use multiple field separators. Use `/` as the field separator, and then use `split()` to split up the filename part.

Comment: Your selected fields are also very off in your given scripts. Not to mention that your first and second scripts here are identical (I'm assuming you forgot `BEGIN {OFS=FS}` or something like that in the second example?

Comment: can i pipe it to split? I thought split only splits the actual file into pieces (as opposed to the filename)

Comment: Not `split` the shell/etc. command. `split()` the awk function.

Comment: @EtanReisner I'm not familiar with the function, but I will look it up. Cheers.

Comment: It's possible with awk, but it's a trivial subsitution on a single line and so more appropriate for sed and you could just do it with bash builtins so - do you REALLY need an awk solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat /tmp/1
/path/to/example_file_123.txt
/path/to/example_file_345.txt

$ awk -F'_' '{split($1,a,".*/"); gsub(a[2],"",$1);print $1$2"_"a[2]"_"$3}' /tmp/1
/path/to/file_example_123.txt
/path/to/file_example_345.txt
```

Comment: basically using '_' as field separator, then using split to get last field 'example' into a[2]. remove 'example' from $1 using gsub and printing all as required with print

Comment: This will fail with lines like `/path/to/example_file_more_123.txt` since you assume that there always will be only two underscore `_`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
awk -F/ '{n=split($NF,a,"_");b=a[1];a[1]=a[2];a[2]=b;$NF=a[1];for (i=2;i<=n;i++) $NF=$NF"_"a[i]}1' OFS=/ file
/path/to/file_example_123.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Perl.

Given:

```
$ echo $e
/path/to/example_file_123.txt
```

Then:

```
$ echo $e | perl -ple 's/([^_\/]+)_([^_\/]+)/\2_\1/'
/path/to/file_example_123.txt
```