# awk: Preserve original field separators when using multiple separators

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to renumber the line_id field in myfile1.txt, each line of which has multiple separators. The end goal is to obtain a python list of dictionaries from this data. So each line would become a dictionary and so the separators, ":" and ",", are really important for me.

Here is a snippet from myfile.txt:

```
"line_id":57,"name":"Test File","seq_number":26,"user":"user1","text_entry":"Entered the room"
"line_id":58,"name":"Test File","seq_number":26,"user":"user1","text_entry":"Left the room"
"line_id":59,"name":"Test File","seq_number":26,"user":"user1","text_entry":"Quit the group"
"line_id":60,"name":"Test File","seq_number":1,"user":"user2","text_entry":"Late to the party"
"line_id":61,"name":"Test File","seq_number":1,"user":"user2","text_entry":"Not responding"
```

The following awk statement works well, albeit i lose all separators. They are replaced with spaces.

```
awk -F [:,] '$2=$2-56' myfile1.json >> myfile2.txt
```

Result is:

```
"line_id" 1 "name" "Test File" "seq_number":26 "user" "user1" "text_entry" "Entered the room"
"line_id" 2 "name" "Test File" "seq_number":26 "user" "user1" "text_entry" "Left the room"
"line_id" 3 "name" "Test File" "seq_number":26 "user" "user1" "text_entry" "Quit the group"
"line_id" 4 "name" "Test File" "seq_number":1 "user" "user2" "text_entry" "Late to the party"
"line_id" 5 "name" "Test File" "seq_number":1 "user" "user2" "text_entry" "Not responding"
```

Now i'm left with the problem of getting back the : and , in the appropriate places. I explored sed but didn't find a simple way to do the subtraction on the second field.

I've been through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30197655/awk-preserve-multiple-field-separators) which does not quite help my requirement. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use comma as input and output field separator
2. Using `split` function in `awk` to split first column on colon
3. Repopulate `$1` after subtracting `56` from 2nd element in split array

**Code:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {split($1, a, /:/); $1 = a[1] ":" a[2] - 56} 1' file

"line_id":1,"name":"Test File","seq_number":26,"user":"user1","text_entry":"Entered the room"
"line_id":2,"name":"Test File","seq_number":26,"user":"user1","text_entry":"Left the room"
"line_id":3,"name":"Test File","seq_number":26,"user":"user1","text_entry":"Quit the group"
"line_id":4,"name":"Test File","seq_number":1,"user":"user2","text_entry":"Late to the party"
"line_id":5,"name":"Test File","seq_number":1,"user":"user2","text_entry":"Not responding"
```

Comment: Thanks much. This worked well for me. So to understand, we leveraged variable a and the "1" at the end denotes first field.

Comment: `1` in the end just prints complete record.